# How can I improve this heavily nested for-loop?

Tags: python, optimization

I have a function which I'd like to optimize, if possible. But I cannot easily tell if there's a better way to refactor (and optimize) this...

Suppose,

```
keys_in_order = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
key_table = { 'A': {'A1': 'one', 'A2': 'two', 'A3': 'three', 'A4': 'four'},
'B': {'B1': 'one-one', 'B2': 'two-two', 'B3': 'three-three'},
... # mapping for 'C', 'D' here
'E': {'E1': 'one-one', 'E2': 'two-two', 'E3': 'three-three', 'E6': 'six-six'}
}
```

The purpose is to feed the above two parameters to the function as below:

```
def generate_all_possible_key_combinations(keys_in_order, key_table):
    first_key = keys_in_order[0]
    second_key = keys_in_order[1]
    third_key = keys_in_order[2]
    fourth_key = keys_in_order[3]
    fifth_key = keys_in_order[4]

    table_out = [['Demo Group', first_key, second_key, third_key, fourth_key, fifth_key]] # just the header row so that we can write to a CSV file later

    for k1, v1 in key_table[first_key].items():
        for k2, v2 in key_table[second_key].items():
            for k3, v3 in key_table[third_key].items():
                for k4, v4 in key_table[fourth_key].items():
                    for k5, v5 in key_table[fifth_key].items():
                        demo_gp = k1 + k2 + k3 + k4 + k5
                        table_out.append([demo_gp, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5])

    return table_out
```

so that the goal is to have a table with all possible combination of sub-keys (that is, 'A1B1C1D1E1', 'A1B1C1D1E2', 'A1B1C1D1E3', etc.) along with their corresponding values in `key_table`.

To me, the current code with five heavily nested loop through the dict `key_table` is ugly, not to mention it being inefficient computation-wise. Is there a way to improve this? I hope folks from code_review might be able to shed some lights on how I might go about it. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you meant to post here http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just posted there. Should I remove this post? If you are one of the moderators, please feel free to do so. Thank you. :)

Comment: I don't quite follow what you are trying to do, but suspect that `itertools` will be the key to simplifying it.

Comment: @user1330974 A moderator has a diamond (♦) after their username. You can always delete your post yourself by clicking the `delete` button at the bottom of your post (above of the tags).

Comment: @KevinGuan, Thank you, Kevin. Seems like some people have submitted suggestions/answers already. I will keep this until a moderator thinks it is absolutely necessary to delete this post. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented with an alternative method. Consider as `key_table` as your main dictionary.

My logic is

1. From this i will get all the possible sub keys from the main dict.

   ```
   In [1]: [i.keys() for i in key_table.values()]
   Out[1]: 
   [['A1', 'A3', 'A2', 'A4'],
   ['C3', 'C2', 'C1'],
   ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
   ['E6', 'E1', 'E3', 'E2'],
   ['D2', 'D3', 'D1']]
   ```
2. Then i made this list of list as a single list.

   ```
   In [2]: print [item for sublist in [i.keys() for i in key_table.values()] for item in sublist]
   ['A1', 'A3', 'A2', 'A4', 'C3', 'C2', 'C1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'E6', 'E1', 'E3', 'E2', 'D2', 'D3', 'D1']
   ```
3. With using `itertools.combinations` implemented the combination of all possible values. It have 5 elements so i given that as a hard code method. You can replace that with `len([i.keys() for i in key_table.values()])` if you more values. Here provides an example of `itertools.combinations`. Then you can understand it.

   ```
   In [83]: for i in itertools.combinations(['A1','B1','C1'],2):
   ....:     print i
   ....:     
   ('A1', 'B1')
   ('A1', 'C1')
   ('B1', 'C1')
   ```

Here is the full code with one line implementation.

```
for item in itertools.combinations([item for sublist in [i.keys() for i in key_table.values()] for item in sublist],5):
    print ''.join(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rahul K P. Do you, by any chance, know if `itertools.combinations` is optimized or not? My specific application doesn't have a lot of keys. I'm just generally curious as to if there is any added benefit of using `itertools` aside from the code looking (less) no longer ugly. :)

Comment: You can use `itertools.combinations`. Benefit is the code looks good and it having more efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Some optimizations:

- The various `key_table[?].items()` could be computed before the nested loop
- You could compute partials of `demo_gp` when they are available: `demo_gp12 = k1 + k2`, `demo_gp123 = demo_gp12 + k3`, etc.  Similar thing could be done with the array of `v`s.

As @JohnColeman suggested, `itertools` would be a good place to look to simplifying it.